# sda parition wrong mounted on startup

Tags: linux, mount, fsck, readonly

I have a Linux Debian Voyage installed on a flash card. Works fine, but the flash disk as /dev/sda1 is mounted as read only:

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext2 (ro,noatime,errors=continue)
```

With

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

it works:

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext2 (rw,noatime,errors=continue)
```

I tried with booting a live cd and running this command:

```
fsck -rfv /dev/sda1
```

Didn't help.
How can I fix that for the boot? Or should I make a small startup-script as a workaround?

Kind regards

**UPDATE**
On startup I saw following:

```
Begin: Checking root file system ... fsck from util-linux 2.25.2
fsck: error 2 (No such file or directory) while executing fsck.ext2 for /dev/sda1
fsck exited with status code 8
done.
Warning: File system check failed but did not detect errors
done.
```

Now I saw following at the end of the boot sequence:

```
Remounting / as read-only ... Done.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. The problem is not the flash disk.

It's because of the operating system "Debian Voyage". At the end of the boot squence, it run's the script

```
/usr/local/sbin/remountro
```

this script remounts the root as read-only.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the flash disk is already mounted at boot. In that case you should edit your `fstab` file (`/etc/fstab`). Your device is probably already in there and you just have to change it to be mounted `rw` instead of `ro`.

See also [Wikipedia: fstab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab).